# wp_editor loses data, perhaps an html_entity_decode problem?

Tags: metabox, wp-editor, wpalchemy

I have a custom meta box that I created with WP Alchemy.  It has two wp_editor fields.  These fields are behaving very strangely.  If I just type simple text into them, they work just fine.  But if I use text with formatting (bold, italics, lots of paragraph breaks, that sort of thing), it will initially save the text just fine.  I save it, I see it there, I look at the site and I see it, and then I go to edit the post again, and the text is gone.

I have the same problem whether I use WP Alchemy to create the meta box or not.

Here is the code for the relevant field of the metabox:

```
<?php
    $content = html_entity_decode($metabox->get_the_value('reviews')); 
    $id = $metabox->get_the_name('reviews');
    $settings = array();

    wp_editor( $content, $id, $settings );
?>
```

I think the problem is somehow related to html_entity_decode.  If I leave that out, it seems to save the data just fine, but of course it then shows HTML, which I don't want.

Is there some alternative to html_entity_decode?  Is there something else I can do to prevent my data from being erased?  I have created dozens of meta boxes with wp_editor, and I have never seen this behavior.  (And I have deactivated all of the plugins on my site to make sure it isn't a plugin conflict.)